# win32 api to geolocate laptop based on wifi and IP address

Tags: c++, winapi, com

How can we fetch the IP address of the laptop and geo-locate or find latitude and longitude ? and How can we geo-locate the laptop using WiFi connection?
I need to implement this in c++/COM without using third party library.
Please suggest some way.

Comment: Build a database of all WiFi hotspots, past, present, and future, and map them to geographical locations. Look up the WiFi hotspot identification - if connected - and query the database. Wow, that was easy.

Comment: If you know public IP address of your internet gateway, you can query your approximate location using https://freegeoip.net/ or similar web api. You don't need COM for this, only WinHttp library.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we fetch the IP address of the laptop

Use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx).

Just keep in mind that the laptop may be connected to multiple networks at the same time, and thus would have multiple IP addresses assigned.  And if the laptop is connected to a network/WiFi router, it is only going to have an IP address from the LAN side of the router, not the Internet side.  You would have to know the router's public Internet IP beforehand, or use uPNP/SNMP to query the router, or use an external service like http://iplookup.flashfxp.com.

> and geo-locate or find latitude and longitude ?

Windows 7 and later has a [Sensor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd318953.aspx) for interacting with various sensors, including GPS devices.  But assuming the laptop does not have GPS installed, then you have to know your Internet IP and then you can perform a location lookup using an external service, such as [FreeGeoIP](http://freegeoip.net) like S.T. suggested.